# When I run a Java process from c# forms, I get no output at all

Tags: c#

I've searched everywhere and still haven't found an answer for this, so here goes.

I'm using this code:

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var jarFile = "C:\\users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Server\\spigot.jar";
        var javaExecutable = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_101\\bin\\java.exe";

        try
        {
            var arguments = String.Format(" -Xms512M -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar {0}", jarFile);
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(javaExecutable, arguments);
            process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
            process.Start();

            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            textBox1.Text = output;
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

and for some reason, I've tried multiple methods and the output seems to return with nothing. I've tried stream reading and cross threading. I don't have it set to no window so that I can see the process.

It appears to run just fine, and even after closing it, it won't change the text. I used message boxes just to make sure it wasn't some weird problem with the textbox, and it gives me no message box either

When I make a loop outside of the try statement to update the text, it just makes my textbox blank.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

between

```
process.Start();
```

and

```
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

do

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

or its overload that takes an int so that you wait for it to finish before trying to read its std out.
There is also an `Exited` event you can hook into if you'd rather do it callback style.

Comment: Thanks, but the program still won't do anything after I tried this and closed the java window.

Comment: Are you sure it is providing output? What happens when you execute the jar manually at the command prompt?

Comment: When I execute the jar from cmd, it looks the exact same when executing it from the java application, the only difference being that you can make it into a batch file with params. If I try to get input from a batch file instead, it would be more ineficient

Comment: Even though you are being vague (I can't see your app running), I am going to assume by "...exact same when executing..." you mean yes, it does write to std out. This is exactly how I capture output of a jar and it works. Maybe write a "hello world" jar and see if it works at all, then at least you know the problem is not the c# code.